# SSRS development: Minimum Configuration for Visual Studio 2017 (VS2017) Install

Tags: xml, reporting-services, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2017-build-tools

What is the **minimum** configuration for Visual Studio 2017 (VS2017) install for SSRS (reporting services) development?

Obviously, one needs the .rdl files (xml), the .rds files with database connection information, and to be able to build, preview, and export the outcome.

Unfortunately, my system is very space-limited so I need to stay as minimal as possible.

Answer (score 0):

The link below has a nice answer:

https://www.jonashendrickx.com/2017/06/26/cannot-open-ssrsssis-projects-vs2017/

Speaking only for myself, method 2 worked better for me.

The key-point is:

Download ‘**Microsoft Reporting Services Projects**‘ from the Visual Studio marketplace.

This is absolutely required to develop SSRS reports.